# Branching issue in C program

Tags: c

My C program needs to skip rest of the code if particular event occurs. I have used continue for that but there is some issue. I am not sure issue is due to that only or something different but it's something logic mistake.

I am sending word to `BoyerMoore_positive(ch[i], strlen(ch[i]) );` function to verify whether it exist in particular word list or not. If exist then increment count values.

for  `skp = BoyerMoore_skip(ch[i], strlen(ch[i]) );` if word is present in this function then I want to skip rest of the code and continue with next word. So I incremented the `i`.

It checks "he is the you she am" this list. But when word is present in this list and come back after performing actions in the function it does not proceed to next word  though I have incremented `i`. It keep looping in `BoyerMoore_skip(ch[i], strlen(ch[i]) );` for some times and then stops without processing next word.

I know this is very specific issue to my program but any kinda help is highly appreciable. I may making some silly mistake.

code:

```
while ((NULL != word) && (50 > i)) 
{
    ch[i] = strdup(word);
    //printf("%s n", ch[i]);

    skp = BoyerMoore_skip(ch[i], strlen(ch[i]) );
    //  printf("skip is %s \n",skp);
    if(skp != NULL)
    {
        i++;
        printf("in\n");
        continue;
    }
    // I tried with keeping  i++ and continue in seperate if(skp != NULL) but same result.
    printf("\n hi2 \n");
    str = BoyerMoore_positive(ch[i], strlen(ch[i]) );
    str2= BoyerMoore_negative(ch[i], strlen(ch[i]) );
    printf("Str is %s \n",str2);
    if (str == NULL)
        t++;
    else {
        printf("%s \n", ch[i]);
        // puts("true");
        pcount += 1;
        printf("Positive count is: %d \n",pcount);
    }

    if(str2== NULL)
        q++;
    else {
        printf("%s \n", ch[i]);
        //  puts("true");
        ncount += 1;
        printf("Nagative count is: %d \n",ncount);
    }

    i++;
    word = strtok(NULL, " ");
    if(str==NULL && str==NULL and skp !=NULL)
    {
        pcount=0;
        ncount=0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your`word` **never** changes once you choose to skip. You reach `continue;` and go right back to the top of the loop, replicating the same word and eventually encountering the same logic.

The code that actually advances `word` to your next token (the `strtok()` logic) is at the bottom of your loop; nowhere near the `continue` that is sending you back to the top. I think you need that logic replicated before the `continue;` *after* you've decided you need to skip and advance to the next token.

In fact, as I look at it now, there is no reason to have it down there either. `word` is only used to populate `c[i]` with a duplicate and is never used anywhere else (that i can see, anyway), so you could in-theory just advance it immediately after making your dupe, thereby having only one snippet of that code in your loop.

Comment: I am little bit confused, where should I place `word = strtok(NULL, " ");`

Comment: @Karimkhan Immediately after `ch[i] = strdup(word);`. Don't forget to remove the one on the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, I spent almost one day!

Answer (score 2):

To test your thesis remove the `continue` statement and add the `} else {` branch with a closing end bracket.

If your code works then you know that the continue is skipping over some required logic.  You can duplicate that missing logic back to the `true` portion of the if and reinstate the `continue` statement.

Comment: I will check this, but Craig has pointer correct mistake I thinnk!

Comment: This is a nice idea, Jack. I use it often when debugging OPC with seemingly odd `continue` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Not actually an answer, but a redesign:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

class BoyerMooreSearch
{
    public:
    typedef std::size_t size_type;

    private:
    static const size_type SkipTableSize = (std::size_t((unsigned char)(-1))) + 1;
    static const size_type Threshold = 5;
    typedef std::array<std::size_t, SkipTableSize> SkipTable;

    public:
    BoyerMooreSearch(const char* substr, size_type substrlen)
    :   m_substr(substr), m_substrlen(substrlen)
    {
        m_skip.fill(m_substrlen);
        size_type n = m_substrlen - 1;
        const char* s = m_substr + 1;
        while(n) m_skip[*s++] = n--;
    }

    BoyerMooreSearch(const char* substr)
    :   BoyerMooreSearch(substr, std::strlen(substr))
    {}

    BoyerMooreSearch(const std::string& substr)
    :   BoyerMooreSearch(substr.c_str(), substr.size())
    {}

    // No copy
    BoyerMooreSearch(const BoyerMooreSearch&) = delete;
    BoyerMooreSearch& operator = (const BoyerMooreSearch&) = delete;

    private:
    inline bool test_size(size_type strlen) const {
        return (m_substrlen && m_substrlen < strlen);
    }

    inline bool brute(size_type strlen) const {
        return m_substrlen < Threshold || strlen - m_substrlen <= m_substrlen;
    }

    public:
    const char* find(const char* str, const size_type strlen) const
    {
        if( ! test_size(strlen)) return 0;
        else {
            const char* end = str + strlen - m_substrlen;

            if( ! brute(strlen)) {

                // Boyer-Moore
                // ===========

                while(str <= end) {
                    if(std::strncmp(str, m_substr, m_substrlen) == 0) return str;
                    str += m_skip[*(str + m_substrlen)];
                }
            }
            else {

                // Brute search
                // ============

                while(str <= end) {
                    if(std::strcmp(str, m_substr) == 0) return str;
                    ++str;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }

    const char* find(const char* str) const {
        return find(str, std::strlen(str));
    }

    const char* find(const std::string str) const {
        return find(str.c_str(), str.size());
    }

    size_type count(const char* str, const size_type strlen) const
    {
        size_type result = 0;
        if(test_size(strlen))  {
            const char* end = str + strlen - m_substrlen;
            if( ! brute(strlen)) {

                // Boyer-Moore
                // ===========

                while(str <= end) {
                    if(std::strncmp(str, m_substr, m_substrlen) == 0) {
                        ++result;
                        str += m_substrlen;
                    }
                    else str += m_skip[*(str + m_substrlen)];
                }
            }
            else {

                // Brute search
                // ============

                while(str <= end) {
                if(std::strncmp(str, m_substr, m_substrlen) == 0) {
                    ++result;
                    str += m_substrlen;
                }
                else ++str;

                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    size_type count(const char* str) const  {
        return count(str, std::strlen(str));
    }

    size_type count(const std::string str) const {
        return count(str.c_str(), str.size());
    }

    private:
    const char* m_substr;
    const size_type m_substrlen;;
    SkipTable m_skip;
};

int main()
{
    BoyerMooreSearch bms("Hello");
    const char* str = "Hello World and Hello People";
    std::cout << "Count: " << bms.count(str) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```